# Java Variable Trace Form

Tags: java, variables, trace

For an assignment I am supposed to complete a table tracing the values of myNum and mySum as well as any output based off of the following code segment:

```
int myNum = 11;
int mySum = 0;

while (myNum >= 0) 
{
myNum--;
mySum += myNum * 5;
}

System.out.println ("myNum: " + myNum);
System.out.println ("mySum: " + mySum);
```

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm having some trouble understanding what this segment will produce. Can anyone help clarify?

Comment: Just run the code!

Comment: Debugging might be more what the op need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a commented version:

```
int myNum = 11; // myNum is 11
int mySum = 0; // mySum is 0

while (myNum >= 0) // repeat the next block (between {}) while myNum is positive or 0
{
    myNum--; // decrease myNum by 1
    mySum += myNum * 5; // add 5 times myNum to mySum
}

System.out.println ("myNum: " + myNum); // output "myNum: " followed by myNum value
System.out.println ("mySum: " + mySum); // same as above by with mySum
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `myNum` will be : `11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1` and the value of `mySum` will be: `0,50,95,135,170,200,225,245,260,270,275,275,270`. So, 
the output will be:

```
    myNum: -1
    mySum: 270
```